# Truncate markup based on char length

Tags: javascript, css

I have markup that is passed via a data base. I need to display this markup in a valid way, but truncated. I've done this in the past by using sub string.

```
 let string = 'this is a string of text';
 string.substr(0, 165);`
```

But I cannot do this with markup, as it wil result in invalid markup being output as the end tags will be removed. 
Example:

```
<h2>Titile</h2>
<p>Some long paragraph</p>
<p>Another long paragraph</p>
<p>Another long paragraph</p>
<p>Another long paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</ul>
... more markup
```

Expected formatted output:

```
Title
Some long paragraph
Another long...
```

Can anyone think of a way of truncating the content using js or css without it resulting in broken html? Thanks.

Comment: In the markup case you've given, what is the expected output?

Comment: I don't think there's any solution to this that doesn't involved parsing the markup, and applying the truncation only to the text inside the markup.

Comment: @Marcus's solution is great, provided it's not specifically truncation at a fixed number of characters that's required.

Comment: Add class name to the p tags or divs or ul and then add the css to truncate and ellipses those tags with their class names in your css file. Never really tried it out myself though, so not quite sure if it will work. Link for the css to be added -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @WaisKamal thanks, i've added expected output

Comment: @MarcusMelodious Thanks, but this would result in each element being truncated, as opposed to the content as a whole. I've added an example of expected output.

Comment: @steve wrap all the elements you want truncated collectively within a new div and add the trucated styles to that div.

Comment: @MarcusMelodious I don't think you can truncate collective content within a div using css. I think you can only truncate on a per element basis, and then it only applies to width, not length.

Comment: @steve then how about adding max height to the wrapper div? Then add a span or p tag right after the wrapper div with `...` or `view more` text that changes the max-height onClick via js to reveal the hidden content. But, you will have cases where the last line can be cuff off half way horizontally. So, conditionally set max-height, by taking into account the position of the element nearest to where you want the max-height and then add or subtract that little bit to avoid the horizontal cut off on the content? Not really sure if this is possible but just throwing it out there in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) rule in CSS. If you require IE support, then a JS solution would be required.

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Output:

```
Titile
Some long paragraph

Another long paragraph...
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gprLx8k9/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can either use css or JS to do truncation, it depends if you want to do this with width of the container or the characters of a string.

Best approach is to do with container's width which is here with this post.

In some case if you still want to **do it with characters'** length you can do it with JS. Which is also attached in the **second solution of this post**. Enjoy your day. :)

```js
text_truncate = function(str, length, ending) {
    if (length == null) {
      length = 100;
    }
    if (ending == null) {
      ending = '...';
    }
    if (str.length > length) {
      return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  };
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.'))
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.',19))
console.log(text_truncate('We are doing JS string exercises.',15,'!!'))
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS truncates a string</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Check the console please.</h1>
</body>
```

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}


.long-and-truncated {
  flex: 1;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.short-and-fixed {
  white-space: nowrap;
  > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child {
  flex: 1;
  h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0; /* or some value */
  h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">

  <div class="flex-child long-and-truncated">
    1. This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="flex-parent has-child">

  <div class="flex-child long-and-truncated-with-child">
    <h2>2. This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="flex-parent has-child">

  <div class="flex-child long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected">
    <h2>3. This is a long string that is OK to truncate please and thank you</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child short-and-fixed">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have any control over the markup that is passed, I do not know what elements will be present etc.

Answer (score 0):

The markup will have to be parsed in the memory. Then get the values from the tags and truncate them. One of the easiest ways to parse this is using JQuery as an arbitrary DOM parser.

Something like this in your case.

```
var memDom = $(htmlString);   //Create a mini DOM in the memory

memDom.filter('p').each((idx, ele) => {

   $(ele).text($(ele).text.substr(0, 165);))  //Truncate each

})
```